# How to keep the loading indicator at the top for inverted FlatList in RN

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When FlatList is inverted, the loading indicator would be at the bottom, how to keep it at the top?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using a work around by wrapping the FlatList in a ScrollView, and leave the refreshControl to ScrollView.

```
const { fetchingMore, onFetchMore } = this.props;
return <ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    flexGrow: 1
  }}
  refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={fetchingMore} onRefresh={onFetchMore} />}
>
  <FlatList
    inverted
    style={styles.list}
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={this.extractItemKey}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Note that it's important to have the `flexGrow: 1` style in scrollView, otherwise the FlatList would flow at the top of the scrollview when it's not full.

Comment: I believe this may produce problem in android due to nested scrolling components usage. Is `scrollEnabled = {false}` not necessary ?

Comment: Hi @surajmalviya thanks for your info, I didn't get to test it on Android yet, will give that a try once I get a chance and get back to you on that.